# How do I compile monero with debugging symbols?

Tags: development, build, compile, building

I've tried `make debug` but when I try to set a breakpoint in gdb I see this:

```
Reading symbols from build/release/bin/monerod...done.
(gdb) b tx_pool.cpp:225
No source file named tx_pool.cpp.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb) b src/cryptonode_core/tx_pool.cpp:225
No source file named src/cryptonode_core/tx_pool.cpp.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb)
```

How can I set up debugging for monero?

Answer (score 1):

"make debug" will build monero with debugging symbols. You will need to debug the binary from build/debug/bin/monerod though, not the one from build/release/bin/monerod.